# Can you identify these SMD Electrolytic capacitors?

Tags: identification, electrolytic-capacitor

I'm fairly sure I need to replace the capacitors in this LCD panel from 1993, but I'm not 100% sure I'm reading them correctly.

I'm guessing that the large ones are 47uF 16V, the medium ones are 10uF 25V and those really small ones are 10uF 16V. I'm not sure what the letter and number combinations at the top are, though.

[image: Capacitors on a Sharp LQ9D01A LCD panel]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for capacitance and voltage rating - How to read electrolytic SMD capacitor labels](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/174453/looking-for-capacitance-and-voltage-rating-how-to-read-electrolytic-smd-capaci)

Comment: Those all look fine to me.  When they go bad, it is usually obvious - they either explode or leak.  Yours look OK.

Comment: What makes you think they are bad?

Comment: There are odd screen artifacts. Most of the time it's just horizontal discolourations extending outward from UI elements like seen here: https://i.imgur.com/abAjf4u.jpg In one case, though, one program has a large black area in one window and when that window is visible the black space is filled with randomly appearing and disappearing blue lines (I didn't get a picture). Old electrolytics can fail without any outward appearance.

Comment: That looks more like artifacts from a VGA connection. Is that how you have your computer hooked up to the display? If so, pull up this page, full screen the window, and run the auto-adjust function on your display: http://www.techmind.org/lcd/phasing.html

Comment: If you actually have a working color LCD display from 1993, it might have some value to a collector. They were quite rare back then.

Comment: It's the screen off a PowerBook 180c that I'm trying to restore. It's not VGA, but I assume it's something that's signal compatible. In any case, there's no "auto-adjust" function and no internet connection. I could draw up a repeating black and white pattern like that page uses, however I don't see how phasing can cause artifacts that extend outward from UI elements, and move when the UI elements move or flickering blue lines against a black background. In my experience phasing causes static artifacts that repeat at regular intervals.

Answer (score 5):

You read them right.

As told in the comments, they look good.

The 'F2', 'F1' and 'D4' are the lot numbers, I see something similar in [ALUMINUM  ELECTROLYTIC  CAPACITORS](http://products.nichicon.co.jp/en/pdf/XJA043/e-ud.pdf), halfway the first page on the left.